# How to OrderBy nested Object value Linq

Tags: c#, linq

**Object**

```
namespace Example
{
    public class ContractorAddValue
    {
        public Member Member { get; set; }
        public List<Addresses> Addresses { get; set; }
        public ICommand AddAddress { get; set; }
    }

    public class Addresses
    {
        public MemberAddress MemberAddress { get; set; }
        public ICommand EditAddress { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Query**

```
public ObservableCollection<ContractorAddValue> GetContractorsOrderByCity()
        {
            var allContractors = (from c in db.Member where c.IsContrator == true select c).ToList();
            //var allContractors2 = db.Member .Include(c => c.MemberAddress).SelectMany(c => c.MemberAddress).OrderBy(c => c.City).Select(c => c.Member ).ToList(); 
            //var allContractors = (from c in db.Member  where c.IsContrator == true select c).OrderBy(c => c.MemberAddress.OrderBy(x => x.City)).ToList(); <= dosent work

            var listContractorAddValue = new ObservableCollection<ContractorAddValue>();

            foreach (var i in allContractors)
            {
                var adressList = db.MemberAddress.Where(x => x.MemberId == i.MemberId).OrderBy(x => x.City).ToList();

                ContractorAddValue contractorAddValue = new ContractorAddValue();
                contractorAddValue.Member = i;
                contractorAddValue.AddAddress = new BaseCommand(() => ContractorsViewModel.SendAddress(i.MemberId ));
                contractorAddValue.Addresses = new List<Addresses>();

                foreach (var a in adressList)
                {
                    Addresses memberAdress = new Addresses();
                    memberAdress.MemberAddress = a;
                    memberAdress.EditAddress = new BaseCommand(() => ContractorsViewModel.SendEditAddress(a.MemberAddressId , i.MemberId ));
                    contractorAddValue.Addresses.Add(memberAdress);
                }

                listContractorAddValue.Add(contractorAddValue);
            }
            return listContractorAddValue;
        }
```

allContractors2 - the order by works, but I retrieve repeating Members. In this approach I tried to use `.Distinct()` after `Select(c => c.Member)` but it doesn't work (the whole query stops working).
My goal is to make an order by `MemberAddress.City`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it appears that a member can have more than one address, so wouldn't that account for the duplicate members showing up? What should happen if the member has more than one address?

Comment: "it appears that a member has more than one address", - yes a member can have more than one address
"What should happen if the member has more than one address?" list of addresses is nested in the list members, members shouldnt duplicate.

I found the answer by trial and error method - distinct() dosent work anyware at query but at loop works ==> foreach (var i in allContractors.Distinct())

Answer (score 0):

I think that this code will work but you need to redefine the Equals method of the ContractorAddValue class.

I added one if statement when you want to add contractorAddValue to the list. First you need to check if your list contains that object. If not you add the object to the list. If yes you need to find that object and merge its addresses list with addresses list from the object you want to add.

```
public ObservableCollection<ContractorAddValue> GetContractorsOrderByCity()
            {
                var allContractors = (from c in db.Member where c.IsContrator == true select c).ToList();
                //var allContractors2 = db.Member .Include(c => c.MemberAddress).SelectMany(c => c.MemberAddress).OrderBy(c => c.City).Select(c => c.Member ).ToList(); 
                //var allContractors = (from c in db.Member  where c.IsContrator == true select c).OrderBy(c => c.MemberAddress.OrderBy(x => x.City)).ToList(); <= dosent work

                var listContractorAddValue = new ObservableCollection<ContractorAddValue>();

                foreach (var i in allContractors)
                {
                    var adressList = db.MemberAddress.Where(x => x.MemberId == i.MemberId).OrderBy(x => x.City).ToList();

                    ContractorAddValue contractorAddValue = new ContractorAddValue();
                    contractorAddValue.Member = i;
                    contractorAddValue.AddAddress = new BaseCommand(() => ContractorsViewModel.SendAddress(i.MemberId ));
                    contractorAddValue.Addresses = new List<Addresses>();

                    foreach (var a in adressList)
                    {
                        Addresses memberAdress = new Addresses();
                        memberAdress.MemberAddress = a;
                        memberAdress.EditAddress = new BaseCommand(() => ContractorsViewModel.SendEditAddress(a.MemberAddressId , i.MemberId ));
                        contractorAddValue.Addresses.Add(memberAdress);
                    }
                    if(!listContractorAddValue.Contains(contractorAddValue)){
                        listContractorAddValue.Add(contractorAddValue);
                    } else {
                       var contAddValue = listContractorAddValue.First(l => l.Equals( contractorAddValue));
                      contAddValue.Addresses.AddRange(contractorAddValue.Addresses);           
                    }
                }
                return listContractorAddValue;
            }
```